# Append some text at the end of the filename

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

There is some file, like *file.txt*, and I want to append COPY at the end of the filename, like *fileCOPY.txt*.

Give me a command for this in the Ubuntu terminal.

I have tried the *mv* command like `mv file.txt fileCOPY.txt`, but this does intend to do what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a file named file.txt its filename is *file* and its extension is *txt*. We want to insert `COPY.` between the filename and the extension of this file.

```
FILE="file.txt"
mv -T $FILE "${FILE%%.*}"COPY."${FILE##*.}"
```

Results: fileCOPY.txt

#### Explanation

`mv` - move (rename) files

Filename:

```
$ echo "${FILE%%.*}"
file
```

File extension:

```
$ echo "${FILE##*.}"
txt
```